# Jquery validation plugin error en checkbox al presionar submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Estoy teniendo problemas al validar un formulario de registro. Cuando le doy a submit sin rellenar ningún campo me aparecen los errores. Si los completo todos menos un checkbox y le doy a submit no me aparece el error del checkbox pero tampoco me manda el formulario al php. En este último caso si clico en el checkbox y lo vuelvo a quitar me aparece el error pero si le doy a submit desaparece.
¿Alguna idea?

Este es el html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.5/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.5/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <form action="#" method="post" id="register-form">

        <div class="input-box">
            <label for="user-register">Usuario</label>
            <input type="text" name="user-register" id="user-register" placeholder="Usuario" required>
        </div>

        <div class="input-box">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email" required>
        </div>

        <div class="input-box">
            <label for="password-register">Contraseña</label>
            <input type="password" name="password-register" id="password-register" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
        </div>  

        <div class="input-box">
            <label for="password-register2">Contraseña</label>
            <input type="password" name="password-register2" id="password-register2" placeholder="Repite contraseña" required>
        </div>   

        <div class="input-box">
            <label for="normal">Normal</label>
            <input type="radio" name="tipo" id="normal" value='normal' required>
            <label for="farmacia">Farmacia></label>
            <input type="radio" name="tipo" id="farmacia" value='farmacia' required>
        </div> 

        <div class="input-box cod" style="display:none">
            <label for="code">Licencia</label>
            <input type="text" name="code" id="code" placeholder="Licencia" required>
        </div>

        <div class="remember-box">
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember2" id="remember2" required>
            <label for="remember2">Términos y condiciones</label>                
        </div> 

        <input type="submit" id="submit_registro" value="Registrar" name="form-boton">

    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Aquí el javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $("input[type=radio]").click(function () {
        const radio = $(this).val();
        if (radio === "farmacia") {
            $(".input-box.cod").show();
        } else {
            $(".input-box.cod").hide();
        }
    });

    $('#register-form').validate({
        focusCleanup: true,
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.appendTo(element.parent());
        },
        rules: {
            "user-register": {
                required: true
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            "password-register": {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6
            },
            "password-register2": {
                required: true,
                equalTo: "#password-register"
            },
            remember2: {
                required: true,
                checkbos: true
            },
            tipo: {
                required: true
            },
            code: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            "user-register": 'error',
            email: {
                required: 'error',
                email: 'error'
            },
            "password-register": {
                required: 'error',
                minlength: 'error'
            },
            "password-register2": {
                required: 'error',
                equalTo: 'error'
            },
        tipo: "error",
        code: 'error',
    remember2: 'error'
        }/*,
         submitHandler: function (form) {
         $.ajax({
         url: form.action,
         type: form.method,
         data: $(form).serialize(),
         success: function (response) {
         alert(response);
         //$('#answers').html(response);
         }
         });
         }*/
    });
});
```

Lo he editado para ir directos al grano y ya de paso se acepta alguna sugerencia con **submithandler** pues no sé si hacerlo así sería lo correcto. Un saludo.

Gracias.

Comment: Debes colocar un [MRE]. Tu problema no tiene nada que ver con PHP, por lo que en tú código de ejemplo no debería haber rastro de ello

Comment: En cuanto al php, trato de que la web tenga dos idiomas por eso para los mensajes utilizo php pero creo que entiendo a lo que te refieres. Entonces, debería también quitar la comprobación del email por remoto. Lo del ejemplo mínimo me cuesta un poco más ya que pensaba que con el formulario html y el javascript era más que suficiente. Soy nuevo, cualquier ayuda es muy bien recibida. Tan pronto llegue a casa lo edito. Gracias!